# How to keep nagios notifying me when the services or hosts are unnormal?

Tags: nagios

I got notification when my services or hosts were not normal, but just once. So I want to keep getting notified when the services or hosts in unnormal state, for example one time 1 minute.

Can I achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not clear what you mean. Repeat of warning is set in the host/service parameter `notification_interval`. There are similar parameters like `check_interval`, `max_check_attempts` and so on to tell Nagios under what  circumstances it should send a notification.

Comment: Yeah, `notification_interval` works. Thank you!